# How to get an average 'spread' from a list of numbers?

Tags: python

Lets say I have a list of numbers:

```
some_numbers = [16.0,  16.01,  24.53,  22.99,  22.72,  22.71,  22.2,  21.36,  21.34,  
21.0,  22.67,  22.62,  15.89,  23.54,  27.0,  21.35,  26.99,  25.46,  22.54,  22.53,  
17.99,  22.13,  17.97,  17.96,  17.95,  22.4,  22.32,  22.25,  22.19,  22.16,  
20.68,  21.74,  15.38,  11.13,  15.82,  22.33,  22.31,  22.23,  22.15,  22.12,  
22.11,  22.07,  18.99,  18.94,  18.86,  18.85,  18.82,  18.81,  16.79,  15.98,  
15.96,  15.94,  15.9,  15.86,  15.85,  15.83,  11.47,  11.46,  11.36,  11.34,  
11.32,  11.28,  11.26,  11.25,  11.21,  11.19,  11.18,  9.99]
```

but the list contains a little too much data, and I want to convey the spread. I want to print 10 of those numbers. With 1 being the highest number and 10 being the lowest number, how could I sort the list and print a range of 10 numbers to represent the spread from highest to lowest?

Lets say the list is `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]` and I wanted a spread of four numbers in that range, the spread would be `[1,5,9,13]`.

Comment: I don't get the 'With 1 being the highest number and 10 being the lowest number' part. Also, what would be the rule for choosing these 10 numbers?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, let me clarify:
lets say the list is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13] and I wanted a spread of four numbers in that range, the spread would be [1,5,9,13]

Comment: It is very unclear, though, what the OP means by 'represent the spread'. I suppose that he doesn't mean 'choose them randomly'. I could imagine trying to choose them more or less regularly spaced from smallest to largest, or so that the standard deviation of the sample is close to the original one, or whatever...

Comment: Yep. Sort em, take `lowest`, take `highest` and take every `n_th` in between ... calculate `n_th` so that it fits. How did you try to solve it? [mcve]?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
sorted(list)[::len(list)/9]
```

Output:

```
[6.34, 11.19, 13.61, 14.56, 15.92, 16.91, 17.97, 19.65, 20.87, 26.81]
```

---

Edit:

`max(list)` won't be on this list if `len(list) % 9 != 0`

Comment: This is perfect, though I do need to make sure the new_list[0] is the lowest number and new_list[10] is the highest number

Comment: You can add it manually using `max(list)` although the interval between last element and max element in the original list probably won't be consistent.

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue for my application. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 7):

Using `np.percentile` and `np.linspace`:

```
import numpy as np

np.percentile(l, np.linspace(100, 0, 10), interpolation='nearest')
# array([27.  , 21.02, 19.7 , 17.99, 16.93, 15.94, 14.57, 13.77, 11.19,
        6.34])
```

Logic:

`np.percentile` with `interpolation='nearest'` returns nearest `q`-th element of given array.

`np.linspace` creates equally spaced 10 elements from 0 and 100 inclusive, in order to make q-th percentiles.

Comment: The problem with this, is I need the numbers to be from the list.

Comment: @Zak You can always add `tolist()` to any given `numpy.array` to make it as a list :)